# Azure app backup creating partial backups

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Azure app service is setup for Backups and it is creating backups with the partial status as "Partially Succeeded".
Error logs are showing some files are skipped from the backup process due to lock on the files.

```
Retrieve site meta-data. 

Backing up the databases. 

Backing up site content and uploading to the blob... 

File skipped - \data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\singleton.job.lock: Sharing violation to C:\Resources\directory\<sometext>.ControllerRole.BackupRestore\<someguid>\package\fs\data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\singleton.job.lock 

File skipped - \LogFiles\ApplicationInsights\status\status_<somesuffix>.json: Sharing violation to C:\Resources\directory\<someguid>.ControllerRole.BackupRestore\<someguid>\package\fs\LogFiles\ApplicationInsights\status\status_<somesuffix>.json 

Uploading metadata to the blob. 

Backup completed!
```

On Azure documentation, there is an option to exclude files in azure backup process https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup#exclude-files-from-your-backup, but I am wondering if there are more required files which are not to be exclude.

Also are these partial backups useful and can we use them? Although steps are mentioned on the page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-restore to restore these partial backup manually. Has any one restored partial backups.

What is the right way to handle the partial backup scenario, by excluding culprit files from backup process or restoring manually these partial backups or is there any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You need create _backup.filter file by yourself. Here is the [offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup) and screen shot. And the understanding of the log file backup is as follows, I hope to get approval.

[image]

As long as the log file is not deleted manually, the data security of the log file can be guaranteed. Part of the backup of the program is for the program, to ensure that the specified version of the program can be restored, but the data still needs the latest, right? So I think that if the log data you need is very important, I suggest that when logging this part of the data, you should save it in the database. Under normal circumstances, the log file does not need to follow the program for backup, because there will be a restore operation after the backup, and the data between the differences between the two versions will be lost after the restore.

**PRIVIOUS**

The function of partial backup is to create a file named _back.filter and set which directories or files do not participate in the backup. Generally, static resource files that never change are not required to be backed up, and others need to be backed up.

It is similar to deploying a website on IIS. Suppose there is an Asset folder, the contents of which are never deleted. We can set this folder without backup. The rest of the folders such as bin, Scripts, Contents, etc. may be because of the program There are changes in the upgrade. This part of the file needs to be backed up. When restoring files, only the contents of the backup will be restored.

Comment: Do you think log files are good to be skipped from backup? Is partial backup useful to restore the azure app service? And where can we find the _back.filter files on azure?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Personally, I don’t think it is necessary to back up the log files. It really needs to be manually backed up every month or every year, because the probability of using the log files is not high, and it is very troublesome to search.@ironman

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, if the backup is clean (not partial) on Azure portal then we get the option to restore the backup from portal by clicking Restore button. So how can we restore the partial backup?

Comment: @ironman I think clicking the restore button and selecting some backup files to restore, if the log files are not backed up and deleted, there is no problem for the application, but the unbacked data is lost. Not everything is so extreme. If important data needs to be backed up, back it up.

Comment: If we get Partial Backup then we do not see Restore Button that is why I am looking for the way to restore the Partial Backups. What is the alternate way if we do not see Restore option?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-restore

Comment: nice, although I have already read this article and I had this link in the question also but still your responses gave me more areas to explore.