# How can i clone an app service via AZ CLI without errors

Tags: azure

I wanted to clone an wordpress on a app service, the new option of azure in another subscription

What ive want

An script that can clone an wordpress on app service into another wordpress on app service in another subscripto

What ive tried
[Azure Webapp Clone powershell script is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71782673/azure-webapp-clone-powershell-script-is-not-working)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning
[Azure app backup creating partial backups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61221484/azure-app-backup-creating-partial-backups)

Result:
New-AzWebApp : Long running operation failed with status 'InternalServerError'.

Error thought Partially Succesfull BackUp since there are a few files that seems to be locked

What ive want

An script that can clone an wordpress on app service into another wordpress on app service in another subscripto

What ive tried
[Azure Webapp Clone powershell script is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71782673/azure-webapp-clone-powershell-script-is-not-working)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning
[Azure app backup creating partial backups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61221484/azure-app-backup-creating-partial-backups)

Result:
New-AzWebApp : Long running operation failed with status 'InternalServerError'.

Error thought Partially Succesfull BackUp since there are a few files that seems to be locked

Comment: did my reply helped you? If so, can you please mark it as the answer so we can close this thread? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering issues with the Azure Web App cloning and backup methods, you can consider an alternative approach using Azure CLI to manually deploy and configure a WordPress instance from one subscription to another. Below is a simplified guide:

#### Prerequisites:

1. **Install Azure CLI:**

   - Ensure that you have the [Azure CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) installed on your local machine.
2. **Export WordPress Database:**

   - Export the WordPress database from the source Azure Web App. You can use tools like `mysqldump` or export from the Azure portal.

#### Steps:

##### 1. **Create a New Azure Web App:**

- In the target subscription, create a new Azure Web App for WordPress using the Azure portal or Azure CLI.

##### 2. **Configure MySQL Database:**

- Set up a new MySQL database for the WordPress instance in the target subscription. Note down the connection details.

##### 3. **Import WordPress Database:**

- Import the previously exported WordPress database into the new MySQL database.

```bash
mysql -h <target_mysql_host> -u <username> -p <database_name> < dump.sql
```

##### 4. Copy WordPress Files:

- Copy the WordPress files from the source Azure Web App to the target Azure Web App. You can use tools like rsync or azcopy.

```
azcopy copy 'https://source-app-name.scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot/' 'https://target-app-name.scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot/' --recursive
```

##### 5. Update WordPress Configuration:

- Update the wp-config.php file in the target Azure Web App with the new MySQL database connection details.

##### 6. Update URLs:

- If necessary, update URLs in the WordPress database to reflect the new environment.

##### 7. Restart Web App:

- Restart the target Azure Web App to apply the changes.

  az webapp restart --name  --resource-group

**Note:**

- If you encountered file locking issues during backup, manually copying the files can help bypass this problem.
- This approach assumes you have control over the MySQL database and can export/import it. Adjustments may be needed based on the specifics of your WordPress setup.
- Ensure that you follow best practices for securing sensitive data, such as MySQL credentials and WordPress configurations.

You can do these steps manually or write scripts to automate these steps and migrate them in an automated way anyway.

Comment: The above looks like a response from ChatGPT. Could you please confirm that it is written from your own experience?

Comment: John, the above was generated using ChatGPT and modified by me, but I provided my own solution to ChatGPT and just asked to generate the steps in a more complete way. Is it a problem to use ChatGPT to complete our answers?

Comment: All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow. See: [What is this site’s policy on content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools? - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy). See also: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/174777)

Comment: I was not aware of this policy. Thanks for letting me know.